# Read all child nodes in XML tag

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have XML file, for example this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Fields>
    <Field name="rampam" />
    <Field name="rampampam" />
</Fields>

<NotFields>
    <Field name="testName1" />
    <Field name="testName2" />
</NotFields>
```

and I want to read all `Field`'s attribute value of `name`  which are under `Fields'. I have tried this code :

```
static public void getInputFields(
        XmlResourceParser parseXML) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {
    int eventType = -1;

    while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
            if (parseXML.getName().equals("Fields")) {
                parseXML.next();
                while (parseXML.getName().equals("Field")) {

                    String fieldName = parseXML.getAttributeValue(null,
                            "name");

                    parseXML.next();
                }
            }
        }
        eventType = parseXML.next();
    }
}
```

and it reads first `Field` but after it gets nulls from `getAttributeValue()`, what am I missing?

p.s. I'm new in parsing xmls.